# Catch "Command+R" in Safari with JQuery

Tags: jquery, safari, keydown, keycode

I need to intercept the browser-reload-functionality in Safari (I know this is usually not something one should do, but in my case this makes sense).

For Windows I just do this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if ( event.which == 116 ) {
        restart();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Do I need to use a JQuery Plugin to capture two Keys at the same time or **is this already implemented in JQuery in some form?**

Also, are the keycodes under Mac the same as they are under windows?
("Command" being the keycode "17" and "r" being "19"?) or is it "55" for the command key and "15" for "r"?

*(using this source: http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2007-05-22/virtual-key-codes*

Comment: I would be piiiiiiisssseeeed off if someone rebound cmd+r to do something other than hard page reload!

Comment: I would usually totally agree with you, but trust me, in this case it makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Jquery plugin to capture keyboard events and th best part is that it will allow you to handle the key events with their names. like if you want to capture CTRL + R then you need not to worry about the key codes, the plugin will handle this by itself.

Check it out here: https://keithamus.github.io/jwerty/

Comment: This looks like an interesting plugin to handle it, but I try to minimize http-requests as much as possible and would really like to avoid another plugin.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that jwerty isn't necessarily a jQuery plugin. It is compatible with jQuery but can be used standalone just as well. Also, Christian, if you're concerned about multiple HTTP requests you should really minify all javascript code into a single file to serve. Have a look at [Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) or [Uglify JS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out without having to use a plugin. I'll verify if it also works on the Mac later (I don't own one), but it works for CTRL+R on a PC:

```
var keys = {};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        keys[event.which] = true;

        //CTRL+R on a PC    
        if(keys[17] && keys[82])
        {
            restart();
            return false;
        }   

        //COMMAND+R an a Mac    
        if(keys[81] && keys[91])
        {
            restart();
            return false;
        }       
    });

    $(document).keyup(function (event) {
        delete keys[event.which];
    });
});
```

This one helped me get there: [Can jQuery .keypress() detect more than one key at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954403/can-jquery-keypress-detect-more-than-one-key-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 0):

You can catch <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on Mac using the next code:

```
$(document).on( 'keydown', function(event){
    if( event.which === 82 && event.metaKey ) {
        alert( 'Your changes will be lost, are you sure to refresh?' );
    }
});
```

**.metaKey** stands for <kbd>⌘</kbd> on Mac and <kbd>⊞</kbd> key on PC.

Comment: I have the same problem but while hitting cmd+r the event does not fire at all. It fires with cmd+shift+r. Any Idea? Maybe the problem is that i bind the handler on 'window'