# Block Ctrl+P event in a web page using jQuery - issue in Safari browser

Tags: jquery, events

I just want to block the user from taking printed copy of the web page. I know that this is not user friendly, but, this is a special scenario, an examination interface where an examinee will attempt questions in an exam. So I don't want them to take prints of the page. I have also blocked other necessary options like context menus, alt Key, save as html etc eventhough it's not good in user's specific view.

I have done it using Jquery, but the code is not working in Safari.

Code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
// Disable Ctrl+P.

   if(!event) event = window.event;
   if (event.ctrlKey && (event.which === 80)) {
     event.preventDefault();
     alert(event.isDefaultPrevented());
   }
});
```

But, the alert is showing the value 'true' and then prompting with Print dialogue box. I have tried by putting `return false` instead of `event.preventDefault();`, then also not working. I couldn't figure out why this weird behaviour in Safari only. Please help. Thanks :)-

Comment: Please *don't* prevent your users from doing anything; any code you have *is* bypassable, and this will only serve to frustrate your users. You realize that users can use context menus as well?

Comment: This is the wrong way to do it. They can still use `Print` from the menu.

Comment: I hate websites that try to do this sort of thing. The only way to protect your content is not to publish it. My Print menu still works fine (and many users don't even know what Control-P does)

Comment: Fun fact: modern web-browsers understand `@media print`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catch "Command+R" in Safari with JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738139/catch-commandr-in-safari-with-jquery)

Comment: Thank you all. I agree with you all. But, this is a special scenario, an examination interface where an examinee will attempt questions in an exam. So I don't want them to take prints of the page. I have also blocked context menus, alt Key,  save as html etc.

Comment: Those who have down voted, I didn't get such a link when I searched for my query. So, how can this be a duplicate question? Also, do I need to make sure that no such related questions are there inside Stack overflow when I'm sincerely putting a query? If so, it is not fair at all.

Comment: Have you blocked the user from hitting `Prt Scr`? How about from taking a picture with a cameraphone?

Comment: Blorgbeard: I've tried. But, later came to know that Print Screen, Alt+Tab etc. keys are Special Keys and hence they can't be prevented normally. Then, if the examination demands security of questions in that exam, we will try to provide it in whatever ways we can. About Camera phone, yes it is possible. But, if the examiners are concerned about that, then they can put invigilators for checking the same. Even then, an examinee wants to do something wrong purposefully, our system is not supposed to prevent him physically from doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
$(document).on("keyup keydown", function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 80){
        alert('Ctrl + P pressed!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JvPnc/)

Comment: Felix: did you check it in safari? alert is ok. But, it is also showing the print dialogue even though we have put 'return false'.