# Detect multiple keys pressed to move a "character/player"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an example of what I have got so far [here (example 1)](http://jsfiddle.net/HelloJoe/8NW2K/), you'll need to click on the 'result' window so the keys will move the character (w, a, s and d keys move the character), also bear in mind that this has not been browser tested and only works in a select few modern browsers.

I can now get the image to move up/down/left/right as wanted and depending on the 'health' it moves a particular speed, and using a good [example I found](http://metatroid.com/articles/CSS3%20transforms%20-%20rotate%20image%20with%20mouse) it rotates along with the mouse too, so it works in a birds eye view styled game.

Now, I'm a little confused about how I can get the image to move diagonally, I've tried using multiple `if` statements linking the possible combinations of keys, but it always takes the last key pressed.

I don't really know how to tackle the problem, do I need to put them in some sort of `while` loop to say while a certain key is pressed move it in that direction? Would that eliminate the need for the diagonal/multiple key press?

```
    if ((key == key_W && key == key_D) || (key == key_w && key == key_d) || (key == key_W && key == key_d) || (key == key_w && key == key_D)) {

        // Player Up/Right

    }
```

Or do I need to set some sort of array to generate a list of keys pressed?

I understand and I'm fully aware making games in Javascript/jQuery isn't the best method to make games, it's an experiment more than anything.

**EDIT**

There is now have a more workable, moving character [here (example 2)](http://jsfiddle.net/HelloJoe/8NW2K/5/), but there is a delay in the movement, so to expand on my question, is there anyway to reduce this?

Comment: Hehe - its fun just to make the little guy run around. cool project. For people checking this out use WASD to move character and it follows mouse too.

Comment: As an aside I could only get this working in IE9, not Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: @Jleagle - you're correct, yes it does although not in Firefox.

Comment: @AndyRose It's probably because I'm using the CSS3 `rotate` which could be causing problems. And I haven't checked it for x-browser compatibility yet. But thank you for point it out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this looks like a fun project so it got me curious and I started to look around. I found an article on Quirksmode that talks about using keycode vs character code. I see that you are detecting both upper and lower case letters. The following blurb seems to indicate that this is unnecessary. This article also has important docs on browser compatibility and special key compatibility between browsers and systems. For instance, the command button on a Mac keyboard. What is it? How is it detected and behaves in various browsers?

> for instance, a lower case 'a' and an upper case 'A' have the same
>   keyCode, because the user presses the same key, but a different
>   charCode because the resulting character is different.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

So then the question becomes, how do you detect multiple key presses. I found this SO answer on it that is remarkably simple and straightforward.

[Can jQuery .keypress() detect more than one key at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954403/can-jquery-keypress-detect-more-than-one-key-at-the-same-time)

```
var keys = {};

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    keys[e.which] = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    delete keys[e.which];
})
```

**Update**

Basically I just brought in the code from above, deleted your diagonal code and iterated over the keys array for all movement operations.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/8NW2K/3/

Comment: Oh, in case it isn't obvious, what I expect you would do is keep all currently pressed keys in the keys array. Then iterate over the array and calculate a move event for each one. I guess technically you could do weird stuff like press up and down simultaneously, resulting in no movement.

Comment: Updated Fiddle with an example.

Comment: Ah, that works! Thank you! I'll probably need to tweak it around a little to make things smoother somehow, but this definitely gets the ball rolling a bit more! I'll wait and see if there are any other answers given with other solutions before I jumped in a mark as top, but this is very appreciated!

Comment: @HelloJoe - yeah, i noticed that the behavior when switching between key combos is not smooth. I'm not sure why that happens. If you find a fix please post it because I would love to see it!

Comment: I will do :) It's strange because if you refresh, and press S and D together, then release S (keeping D pressed), it will smoothly carry on just going from down/right to just right. But then after that it has the delay. I'm thinking it could be something with the `keyup` and it deleting itself. I'm not entirely sure though, I'll keep trying, it's fun messing around with it all haha

Answer (score 3):

Jwerty is a great library which handles this sort of thing, i suggest you check it out:

https://keithamus.github.io/jwerty/

It's compatible with jQuery too!

Comment: This looks interesting, this could definitely come in handy at some point, thank Jleagle :)