# jQuery handling keypress combinations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that when `keypress` event occurs then we can access which key is pressed by object's event property `keycode`, but I need to know how do we can handle `keypress` combinations through jQuery like `ctrl + D` ..etc?

In the following code I tried to do something like :

```
$(document).on("keypress", function(e) { 
    if( /* what condition i can give here */ )           
        alert("you pressed cntrl + Del");
});
```

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655202/detect-multiple-keys-on-single-keypress-event-on-jquery/10655316#10655316
On the side note...prefer my answer (hehe)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

jQuery already handles this for you:

```
if ( e.ctrlKey && ( e.which === 46 ) ) {
  console.log( "You pressed CTRL + Del" );
}
```

Comment: +1 for ctrlKey. But the link I provided works for non-special keys too

Answer (score 7):

I know that this is an old question that has already been answered, but the answer marked as correct did not work for me. Here is a simple and easy method for catching the key combinations I wrote:

**NOTE:** This example is catching `ctrl + space` combination, but you can easily change it to any other keys.

```
    var ctrlPressed = false; //Variable to check if the the first button is pressed at this exact moment
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.ctrlKey) { //If it's ctrl key
        ctrlPressed = true; //Set variable to true
      }
    }).keyup(function(e) { //If user releases ctrl button
      if (e.ctrlKey) {
        ctrlPressed = false; //Set it to false
      }
    }); //This way you know if ctrl key is pressed. You can change e.ctrlKey to any other key code you want

    $(document).keydown(function(e) { //For any other keypress event
      if (e.which == 32) { //Checking if it's space button
        if(ctrlPressed == true){ //If it's space, check if ctrl key is also pressed
          myFunc(); //Do anything you want
          ctrlPressed = false; //Important! Set ctrlPressed variable to false. Otherwise the code will work everytime you press the space button again
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: brilliant, the accepted answer didn't work for me either. Thanks for adding your solution. Works like a charm.

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte Happy to help :)

Comment: Same here, nothing else worked. Good job :)