# How can I detect CTRL-V in JavaScript for IE and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, paste

I'm trying to detect when the user presses Ctrl + V in JavaScript.

```
jQuery(document).on('paste', function() {alert('text pasted!')})
```

It works well with Chrome (v37). But it does not work with Firefox (v32) and IE (v11), as you can try on this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7N6Xq/410/

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT - 2014-09-17 - need the clipboard content.

I cannot just rely on key detection, because I need the clipboard content which is only available through a paste event (there is no clean other way to access it). In this JSFiddle, I get the event and display the text (works on Chrome only)

http://jsfiddle.net/7N6Xq/412/

My final goal is to get an image from the clipboard and directly send it to the server.

Comment: You should be able to get your answers from the combination of these two threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671822/jquery-handling-key-combinations (detecting the "Ctrl" key) & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655202/detect-multiple-keys-on-single-keypress-event-on-jquery (detecting key combinations)

Comment: [mouse trap](http://craig.is/killing/mice) works well, if you just want to use a small library.

Answer (score 7):

This is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7N6Xq/411/). It worked well on Chrom & Firefox &IE10
Here is code:

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 86) {
        alert("!");
    }
});
```

Comment: But it does not give you the pasted content through the event. The question should be formulated differently, by displaying the clipboard text in the alert.

Comment: @JohnRizzo Soryy, I can't follow you. Do you mean is there a different between the event `paste` and the event `keydown` ?

Comment: Yes. For security reasons, it's not possible to initiate the reading of the user's clipboard from JavaScript. The only thing we can to is to wait for the user to initiate a paste event (for example with Ctrl + V) and access the clipboard through that event.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just paste on displayed text.  You have to create an input area where they can paste, an `<input>` or a `<textarea>` or similar. It will inherit the `onpaste` handler so you don't have to set it directly on the input element, but it won't fire outside of one in most browsers.

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lznvm8x9/

I'm on a Mac, so I can't test IE, but the above works in Firefox, as well as Safari and Opera.

If you want to detect control-V as a key chord independent of the actual paste functionality, you can use `keydown`/`keyup` events, but then you hit the cross-platform issues - do you want it to still be control-V on a Mac, where paste is usually command-V, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use `keydown` and `keyup` + codes for keys instead of your actual approach.

Comment: But it does not give you the pasted content through the event. The question should be formulated differently, by displaying the clipboard text in the alert.