# Enter key down does not open drop down in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, typescript

Enter key does not open drop down in Mozilla.
Works fine in Chrome.(Its chrome default behavior)

Trying something like this to achieve it in Mozilla

```
var self = this;
    $('select').on('keyup', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) { $(this).trigger('click'); }
    });
```

Comment: try `e.which` instead of `e.keyCode` but I feel it works fine **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/6w32teek/2/)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Nope it doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/moz_shortcuts.html), the shortcut for Mozilla is Alt+Down Arrow, for select boxes, arrow keys to scroll, Enter to select.

Comment: thanks.
can we manually trigger a event for alt + drown arrow?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery), [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/altKey) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671822/jquery-handling-key-combinations)

Comment: Enter key does not open drop down in Internet Explorer as well. Above solution works for IE as well. The shortcut of Alt+Down Arrow, for select boxes opens dropdown in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying in select box? If yes then trigger is not possible.

You can try on some other elements(div,ul li,..) similar to select box.

Comment: Is this still valid anno 2018? I'm trying to let a <select> open on enter when parent has focus, but none seem to work :(