# HTML\Javascript - get ATL\CTRL\SHIFT key press

Tags: javascript

Is there the ability to capture any key press? i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> key press (with no other key press).

In the snippet below (checked under Chrome), I am able to capture the shift only when other "regular" key was pressed.

**UPDATE**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function onKeyPressed(event) {
            event = event || window.event;
            var code = event.keyCode;
            var key = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
            var shift = event.shiftKey;
            var alt = event.altKey;
            var ctrl = event.ctrlKey;
            var which = event.which;
            var str = "code = " + code + "\n" +
                      "key = " + key + "\n" +
                      "shift = " + shift + "\n" +
                      "alt = " + alt + "\n" +
                      "ctrl = " + ctrl + "\n" +
                      "which = " + which;
            alert(str);
        };

        function onClick(event) {
            event = event || window.event;
            var x = event.clientX;
            var y = event.clientY;
            var str = "x = " + x + "\n" +
                      "y = " + y;
            alert(str);
        };

        function onKeyUp(event) {
            alert("onKeyUp");
        };

        function onKeyDown(event) {
            alert("onKeyDown");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onmousedown="onClick(event)" onkeypress="onKeyPressed(event)" onkeyup="onKeyUp(event)" onkeydown="onKeyDown(event)"></body>
</html>
```

How can those keys be captured?

Comment: Isn't it just `if(event.keyCode == x)` where x is the key code of shift/ctrl/alt?

Comment: yet another jQuery solution, with which i won't go fishing for downvotes :) http://craig.is/killing/mice

Comment: Ooops, sorry, [the duplicate I found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655202/detect-multiple-keys-on-single-keypress-event-on-jquery/10655273#10655273) was jQuery-specific. Still, easy enough to adapt, I think the only jQuery aspect of it is hooking the events, which is easy enough to mod.

Answer (score 4):

There's a very nice new JS library that does a great job of tracking keyboard events in the browser.

It's called Mousetrap. Here's the link: http://craig.is/killing/mice

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Is jQuery allowed? If so take a look at this:

http://www.stepanreznikov.com/js-shortcuts/

otherwise you may give @Max Gherkins suggestion a chance

Comment: i like this idea! :) thanks, but i am looking for a native way to achieve it.

Comment: Ok @MrRoth - take a look at craig.is/killing/mice it will do the trick for you! :)

Comment: thanks you again!! :) but i do not wish to use a library, i want to write one of my own. so what is the trick instead of doing reversed engineering to the code?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK You have to use the keyup or keydown event to capture the shift, keyPress does not capture it. Check out [this list](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) of keys captured by each event if you need more details. Since shift is a modifier key it's not captured. Why this is the case I cannot explain.

Comment: please see my update. i have included the `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` handlers, though only `onkeydown` is called when a key is pressed.