# Multiple Jquery actions running at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework

The example for this question is http://jsfiddle.net/4ac5u/

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       $("#left").css( "background-color", "red" );
       x = x-1;
       $("#ball").css( "margin-left", x*10 );
       return false;
    }
});
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       $("#left").css( "background-color", "#fff" );
       return false;
    }
});
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
       $("#up").css( "background-color", "red" );
       y = y-1;
       $("#ball").css( "margin-top", y*10 );
       return false;
    }
});
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
       $("#up").css( "background-color", "#fff" );
       return false;
    }
});
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
       $("#right").css( "background-color", "red" );
       x = x+1;
       $("#ball").css( "margin-left", x*10 );
       return false;
    }
});
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
       $("#right").css( "background-color", "#fff" );
       return false;
    }
});
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
       $("#down").css( "background-color", "red" );
       y = y+1;
       $("#ball").css( "margin-top", y*10 );
       return false;
    }
});
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
       $("#down").css( "background-color", "#fff" );
       return false;
    }
});
```

In this example I have different Jquery keydown listeners waiting for a specific key press, and on that keypress I want to move a ball in a certain direction (in this example using the css function to change the margin).

The issue is that you can only move in one direction at a time. Is it possible to have it so that if I have the down arrow and the right arrow down at the same time I move towards the bottom left part of the screen, not just right or down?

I have thought about possibly finding a way to alternate between them if both are pressed, but I'm not sure how that would work. Or if there is some way to do threading.

Also I'm not sure if there is a way to also make it not cancel out on pressing a new button while you are still holding the other down.

Comment: Why not just have the `e.keyCode` checks in an else-if on the same event handler function? [Example in a JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7QVSE/)

Comment: why are you writing anything heavily based on user interaction using jquery? what is the purpose of moving a ball? writing a game? use something else.

Comment: What would you suggest @tenub?

Comment: Here you have:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655202/detect-multiple-keys-on-single-keypress-event-on-jquery

Cheers

Comment: I was thinking possible a simple game, but more just general keyboard control

Answer (score 1):

Combine all of your keydowns and keyups into one function with multiple if statements.  Check for combinations first, and then check for single arrow presses.  That should resolve the issue.

If you want to support users being able to move the ball around fluidly, I'd look into the example given here: http://jsfiddle.net/kzXek/.  This example includes handling pressed down arrow keys to provide fluid movement.

```
// Made by RobseRob.dk
// Please give credit.
// Vars which contains key state
var movLeft = 0;
var movRight = 0;
var movUp = 0;
var movDown = 0;

var score = 0;
$(function() {
    // Keydown listener
    $("body").keydown(function(e) {
        ek = e.keyCode;
        if (ek==37) movLeft=1;
        if (ek==39) movRight=1;
        if (ek==38) movUp=1;
        if (ek==40) movDown=1;
    });
    // Keyuo listener
    $("body").keyup(function(e) {
        ek = e.keyCode;
        if (ek==37) movLeft=0;
        if (ek==39) movRight=0;
        if (ek==38) movUp=0;
        if (ek==40) movDown=0;
    });
});
```

Comment: This could be further improved by using `$(document)`, delegating the events and chaining them. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this code:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var dirs = {
    left: false,
    top: false,
    right: false,
    bottom: false
};
$(document).keydown(function(e){
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37: dirs.left = true; return false;
    case 38: dirs.top = true; return false;
    case 39: dirs.right = true; return false;
    case 40: dirs.bottom = true; return false;
  }
});
$(document).keyup(function(e){
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37: dirs.left = false; return false;
    case 38: dirs.top = false; return false;
    case 39: dirs.right = false; return false;
    case 40: dirs.bottom = false; return false;
  } 
});

var checkLeft = function() {
  if (dirs.left) {
    $("#left").css( "background-color", "red" );
    x--;
  } else {
    $("#left").css( "background-color", "#fff" );
  }
}

var checkRight = function() {
  if (dirs.right) {
    $("#right").css( "background-color", "red" );
    x++;
  } else {
    $("#right").css( "background-color", "#fff" );
  }
}

var checkTop = function() {
  if (dirs.top) {
    $("#up").css( "background-color", "red" );
    y--;
  } else {
    $("#up").css( "background-color", "#fff" );
  }
}

var checkBottom = function() {
  if (dirs.bottom) {
    $("#down").css( "background-color", "red" );
    y++;
  } else {
    $("#down").css( "background-color", "#fff" );
  }
}

var moveBall = function() {
  $("#ball").css({
    "margin-left": x*10,
    "margin-top": y*10
  });
}

setInterval(function() {
  checkLeft();
  checkRight();
  checkTop();
  checkBottom();

  moveBall()
}, 50);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/26XWw/

Answer (score 0):

Create an Array of Booleans (left, right, up, down) and on a `setInterval` check which ones are set to `true`

Here would be your updated code:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var keysDown = [false, false, false, false];
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            keysDown[0] = true;
            break;
        case 38:
            keysDown[2] = true;
            break;
        case 39:
            keysDown[1] = true;
            break;
        case 40:
            keysDown[3] = true;
            break;
    }
});
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            keysDown[0] = false;
            $("#left").css("background-color", "#fff");
            break;

        case 38:
            keysDown[2] = false;
            $("#up").css("background-color", "#fff");
            break;

        case 39:
            keysDown[1] = false;
            $("#right").css("background-color", "#fff");
            break;

        case 40:
            keysDown[3] = false;
            $("#down").css("background-color", "#fff");
            break;

    }
});

function checkBallMoving()
{
    if (keysDown[0] === true) {
        $("#left").css("background-color", "red");
        x = x - 1;
        $("#ball").css("margin-left", x * 10);
    }
    if (keysDown[1] === true) {
        $("#right").css("background-color", "red");
        x = x + 1;
        $("#ball").css("margin-left", x * 10);
    }
    if (keysDown[2] === true) {
        $("#up").css("background-color", "red");
        y = y - 1;
        $("#ball").css("margin-top", y * 10);
    }
    if (keysDown[3] === true) {
        $("#down").css("background-color", "red");
        y = y + 1;
        $("#ball").css("margin-top", y * 10);
    }
}
setInterval(function () {
    checkBallMoving();
}, 100);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4ac5u/11/)**

Comment: Interesting, I tried that out and it didn't seem to work.     `$(document).keyup(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 39 && e.keyCode == 40) { 
           y = y+1;
       x = x+1;
       $("#ball").css( "margin-top", y*10 );
       $("#ball").css( "margin-left", x*10 );
    }
});`

Comment: Put it on the `keydown` not just the `keyup`

Comment: This is example is wrong on so many levels (no caching variables, no delegated events, using setInterval) and doesn't solve the problem at hand (I can press multiple keys in 500ms without a problem). Instead it makes it even more difficult to read, understand and debug!

Comment: Reducing the `setInterval` duration doesn't improve anything. Please look at the other answers for better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the keydowns in an array or object and then check for all the ones that were pressed:

Here you have:

[Detect multiple keys on single keypress event in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655202/detect-multiple-keys-on-single-keypress-event-on-jquery)

Cheers