# how can i bind several keys same time while keep firing keydown or up event when another key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, game-engine

Some might think its a duplicate of:

[JavaScript multiple keys pressed at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once)

[Detect multiple keys on single keypress event in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655202/detect-multiple-keys-on-single-keypress-event-on-jquery)

[Can jQuery .keypress() detect more than one key at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954403/can-jquery-keypress-detect-more-than-one-key-at-the-same-time)

or my old post : [How can I catch 2+ key presses at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20962033/how-can-i-catch-2-key-presses-at-once#20962085)

But the answer they offer does not solve the issue i am facing.

Lets say you click on left key and hold then add up key for a second and then release up key.  in the above questions the "keydown" event stop firing until you release it and click it again. E.G :
http://jsfiddle.net/gFcuU/586/ open console log and try the above steps you'll see what i am talking about.

You can also try my old code and see the same issue at : http://jsfiddle.net/dB553/1/

My solution to it was setting an interval that will act like "refresh" for the whole "game" you can see it at: http://jsfiddle.net/2Nn9T/3/

you'll notice how smooth the movement compared to the other way.

**My question is: ** is there a better way to achieve the same thing without intervals ?

The interval I set looks like:

```
this.fnStartTimers = function(){
    this.oRgfInterval = setInterval(function(){ that.fnRefreshGame(); },this.iRefreshGameFrequency);
    this.oGcInterval = setInterval( function(){ that.fnGlobalCooldown(); } ,this.iGlobalCoolDown);
}
```

Comment: Looking in the code, I think you are on the right path with intervals. You could use helper function to test for key combinations, but action game is likely to be interval based.