# Detecting Command + C keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to with jQuery keyCode to detect Command + C? The keycode only sends one key, not the pressed combo. I'm looking to setup a binding to detect Command + C. I've seen some keyboard shortcut plugins but would like to avoid adding an additional library for one simple binding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655202/detect-multiple-keys-on-single-keypress-event-on-jquery

Comment: Are you trying to detect if the user is copying something? If so, Command + C detection would only work for Mac users.

Answer (score 23):

you can check the `ctrlKey` property of the event. (possibly `metaKey` if it's on mac, not sure)

for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 67 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)){
       //it was Ctrl + C (Cmd + C)
    }
});
```

Comment: Using (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) adds Mac support. I confirm as well. Thanks.