# How to make a div appear with JavaScript with keypresses

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show/enable a div whenever I type a certain key-combination in the right order.

For example: 'open console{enter}'
Now, there is no input field, no nothing. I simply open my site, type the text and a div should pop up. Such as a 'secret menu'.

How can I accomplish this without an actual inputfield?

Also, what could be the pros and cons?

Comment: also be careful with this 'secret' things client side, as all the source code is accessible by the user

Comment: @Paramone, is it essential that there is no actual input field? I have successfully captured keystrokes with a 1px-wide input field that has no enclosing form, using jQuery library.

Comment: @JohnRC Actually, that doesn't even sound bad. Could you elaborate a little? Do you see the inputfield / how do you target it? It is however essential and necessairy that it is 'invisable'.

Comment: Looks like @Snorlax's answer is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("keypress", function (e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $("#div").show();
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ve6crpne/

`e.which` is which key. If the key is 13 (ENTER/Return) it will show the div with id = div.

If you wish to detect multiple keys in a row, add each key to a map and check it afterwards. Just like the duplicate question, which can be seen here: [Detect multiple keys on single keypress event in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655202/detect-multiple-keys-on-single-keypress-event-on-jquery) - Really simple.

Comment: Your code doesn't do what he asked, I don't understand how you've got 3 upvotes. If your answer is "follow the answer in this other SO question" then leave it flagged as duplicate.

Comment: Because I edited my post after it was duplicated. Did I answer his "How to make a div appear with JavaScript with keypresses" question? Yes. I added the "add to map" part after it was marked as a duplicate.

Comment: It wasn't "with *any* keypresses" was it? It was specific keypresses. You've wrote code that shows an element when enter is pressed. He didn't ask for that once in the question.

Comment: this does not answer the question. This code listens to only one keystroke, question says : "certain key-combination in the right order".