# Detecting Key Press in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a menu bar on a web based program that is built using jsp. Usually, my company uses java scriplets to add functionality, but I have been reading about JSTL and was wondering if there was a way to determine if two keys were pressed simultaneously using JSTL. Also, is there any general rules or conventions to be followed when revising scriplets into JSTL?

Comment: jstl,jsp..all these are server technologies.If you want to capture any event at client side, javascript is the way to go !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to detect key input using JSTL. As far as I know JSTL, it is a collection of these five types of tags:

**Core Tags:** used for accessing variables, iterating objects, and (almost) all of the standard loops and if-else statements that you would expect in a programming language.

**Formatting tags:** Dates, strings etc

**SQL tags:** Database stuff

**XML tags:** like core, but for xml

**JSTL Functions:** Functions like `contains`, `join`, `split`, `substring` etc

You can read more about it here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm

Your best bet for creating a key listener, is javascript. Take a look at this post for more info: [Detect multiple keys on single keypress event in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655202/detect-multiple-keys-on-single-keypress-event-on-jquery)

For the other part of your question, I have found particularily two answers already existing on stackoverflow, to be most helpful:
[How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?rq=1) 
[How to avoid using scriptlets in my JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188706/how-to-avoid-using-scriptlets-in-my-jsp-page)

**EDIT:** As mentioned in the comments, JSTL works on the server side of a web application. user input happens on the client side, and is therefore out of scope for JSTL. Javascript is the way to go.