# Submit a PHP Form with any of keyboard shortcut key

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

i wants to submit a php form with any of function key or a Any of keyboard shortcut key.

I try following code. In that i do operation using keyboard keycode. but its not submits the form.
**Press "TAB" button from Keyboard**

```js
document.onkeydown=function(evt){
        var keyCode = evt ? (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) : event.keyCode;
        if(keyCode == 9)
        {
            //your function call here
            document.test.submit();
            alert("Key Pressed");
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    echo $search = $_POST['search'];
}
?>
<body>
<form name="test" action="#" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="search" />
</form>
</body>
```

I wants to submit a PHP form with any of Function key or Any of combinations or shortcut key.
So How can I do it with JQUERY,JS,AJAX OR PHP.

Comment: `any of Function key or Any of combinations or shortcut key`:- what happen if user want to type `a@gmail.com` (conside `@`there). Just after hiting `@` from will submit and `gmail.com` will never be added. it's not a good practice to do in this way. But wait. You will get answer for-sure

Comment: for that i need to use only key combinations.so is there any way to submit a form using any of key combinations.
Like Ctrl + A

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655202/detect-multiple-keys-on-single-keypress-event-in-jquery/10655316#10655316

Comment: You form to do get submitted on tab click . What else you want  ?

Comment: Its not working bro. See [link](https://jsfiddle.net/webster18/psdjcdv4/)

Comment: I want to submit a Form With Any Of Keyboard Key Combination

Comment: any of the keyboard key or only function keys ?

Comment: Any Of Keyboard Key Combination Or Function Key.
any of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I founded a JS to Allow Form Submit using keyboard key combination.
It quite easy.
See Code

```
    shortcut.add("Ctrl+B",function() {
    document.getElementById("sbmt").click();
    alert("Form Submitted...");
    },{
      'type':'keydown',
      'propagate':true,
      'target':document
    });
```

When Press Ctrl + B Form Was Submits.
This is Link to JS 
[openjs To Allow Shortucut](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/)

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work.

```
document.onkeydown=function(evt){
    var keyCode = evt ? (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) : event.keyCode;
    if(keyCode == 9)
    {
        //your function call here
        document.forms["test"].submit();
        alert("Key Pressed");
    }
}
```

Check this code in your local not on third party. This will work perfect on localhost. this is work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this if you want to submit on click of any function keys
**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/psdjcdv4/3/)**

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
   if(e.which <124 && e.which >111){
   alert('function keys');
   //submit your form here
   }

});
```