# Blocking special characters with "keyup" vs "keydown" vs "keypress"

Tags: jquery, events, keypress

I am trying to limit textbox input to numbers only, 0-9, without using regular expression. And, below is my code:

```js
$("input[type='text']").on('keypress', function(e){
  if(e.which>=48 && e.which<58){
      return true;
  }else{
      return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My question is: "in this case, why only **keypress** prevents the input of special characters?"

Comment: by the way there is **type=number** in html , you may use it

Comment: I can use  <input type="number"> but I do not like the little increase/decrease arrows at the very end of the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

`keypress` doesn't return the same key codes. For example, if you add `console.log(e.which)` to the function and press backspace, nothing will fire. But if you press another key, it will. Also, keypress detects "shift + number" combinations as odd keycodes, so they return false in your function. For instance, "shift + 1" returns 33, but 33 should mean "page up".

`keyup` doesn't work because characters are rendered on keydown, therefore, keyup is too late. (You can't have a `keyup` event without a `keydown` occurring first.)

`keydown` doesn't prevent the special characters because these special characters require a combination of keydown/keup events (shift plus number). So the `keydown` returns true as soon as the number is pressed even if the shift key was held down and returned false. In order to address that you will need to `map` them to detect the combination as described here: [Detect multiple keys on single keypress event in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655202/detect-multiple-keys-on-single-keypress-event-in-jquery)

Comment: Use of "keydown" allows typing non-number characters: !@#$%^&*(). Also, it prevents use of "back space/delete key/ navigational arrows", I want these keys to work!

Comment: That's more clear than your original question. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks. So that was the "Shift" key messing up :)