# Detecting What Key Was Pressed in jQuery keypress

Tags: jquery, html, document, keypress

I want to use hotkeys in one of my pages. However, it seems that the only key that can be detected in my hotkeys is the Enter Key.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    switch (key)
    {
        case 72:
          alert("H");
          break;
        case 82:
          alert("R");
          break;
        case 66:
          alert("B");
          break;
        case 13:
          alert("ENTER");
          break;
        default:
          alert("Invalid");
    }
});
```

Reference of key code values: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: What is the output if you `alert(key)`?

Comment: these codes works fine in my project. maybe it is because of your charset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.charCode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/event.charCode#Notes) (via the jQuery docs for [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)), `e.which` returns [Unicode character codes](http://unicode-table.com/en/#0048), so `H` could be either 72 or 104 (`h`) depending on text case.

> In a keypress event, the Unicode value of the key pressed is stored in
>   either the keyCode or charCode property

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/sZmST/)

Comment: This answered my question. Thanks. But I still have a question. I want to have multiple hotkeys, as I've said in the question, and I want to use the JS switch instead of multiple `if`s and `if...else`. Is it possible to use 2 cases on a single function? something like:

`switch(key) {`
`case 72 || case 104: //function to be called;`
`break;`
`}`

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: @KevinHandogTresuelo In this case you need to either need to use the modifier keys (Shift, Alt, Ctrl) or else store the currently pressed/released keys in a variable. It's all discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954403/can-jquery-keypress-detect-more-than-one-key-at-the-same-time)