# How to watch for a keypress combination in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, keypress

I'm trying to get my controller to watch for a combination of keys.  For argument's sake, let's say: up up down down left right left right b a.  How can I get angular to look out for these regardless of where in the page the user currently is?

Comment: If you want to trigger code with a combination of keys on keyPress (eg `Ctrl + a`), have a look at this (using AngularJS factory):
https://jsfiddle.net/firehist/nzUBg/

Comment: Keep in mind that you [could](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4954431/1927876) do `if (e.ctrlKey && e.which === number)`.

Answer (score 12):

Looks like you can use the [ng-keydown](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngKeydown) to do this.

Here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1g9Y7o?p=preview).

For this sample, I just bound `ng-keydown` to `<body>`.  Works pretty well to catch all the keyboard events globally.

As @charlietfl points out, `ng-keydown` registers a lot of keyboard events so to make this usable would be a lot of work.  For example, if you were trying to listen for a combination (like `ctrl` + `r`), then the `ctrl` key will register many times.

**JS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {


    $scope.keyBuffer = [];

    function arrays_equal(a,b) { return !(a<b || b<a); }

    $scope.down = function(e) {

      $scope.keyBuffer.push(e.keyCode);

      var upUp = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65];
      if (arrays_equal(upUp, $scope.keyBuffer)) {

        alert('thats it!');
      }
    };

  });
```

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-keydown="down($event)">
```

Comment: was playing with this but have to check for break in squence by user, empty array if it breaks, index existing array before push new key...starts getting time consuming making it bulletproof

Comment: @charlietfl yes, exactly.  Because `ng-keydown` repeats if you hold down the key.  I hadn't checked this out until now.  maybe `ng-keyup` would work better?

Comment: lots more to it once you dig in..

Comment: This works, I've also added buffer functionality so keyBuffer is never longer than upUp.  As Kos Prov mentioned in a different answer on this thread, it does have the disadvantage that digest is called on every single keypress.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using a different way to do it.

```
$scope.keyboard = {
  buffer: [],
  detectCombination: function() {
    var codes = {};

    this.buffer.forEach(function(code) {
      codes['key_' + code] = 1;
    });

    if ((codes.key_91 || codes.key_93) && codes.key_8) {
      // I'm looking for 'command + delete'
    }
  },
  keydown: function($event) {
    this.buffer.push($event.keyCode);
    this.detectCombination();
  },
  keyup: function($event, week) {
    this.buffer = [];
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Detecting Backspace-Key (Mac) and Del-Key (PC):

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-keydown="keyDown($event)">..<body>

$scope.keyDown = function(value){
    if(value.keyCode == 46 || value.keyCode == 8) {
        //alert('Delete Key Pressed');
    }
};
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP asks about keypress combination

Answer (score 2):

This is all untested, but you could use [ng-keypress](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angKeypress)

```
<body ng-keypress="logKeys($rootScope,$event)">...</body>
```

To call a function something like:

```
appCtrl.$scope.logKeys = function($rootScope,$event){
    $rootScope.keyLog.shift(); // Remove First Item of Array
    $rootScope.keyLog.push($event.keyCode); // Adds new key press to end of Array
    if($scope.$rootScope.keyLog[0] !== 38) { return false; } // 38 == up key
    if($scope.$rootScope.keyLog[1] !== 38) { return false; }
    if($scope.$rootScope.keyLog[2] !== 40) { return false; } // 40 = down key
    if($scope.$rootScope.keyLog[3] !== 40) { return false; }
    if($scope.$rootScope.keyLog[4] !== 27) { return false; } // 37 = left key
    if($scope.$rootScope.keyLog[5] !== 39) { return false; } // 39 = right key
    if($scope.$rootScope.keyLog[6] !== 37) { return false; }
    if($scope.$rootScope.keyLog[7] !== 39) { return false; }
    if($scope.$rootScope.keyLog[8] !== 65) { return false; } // 65 = a
    if($scope.$rootScope.keyLog[9] !== 66) { return false; } // 66 = b

    $rootScope.doThisWhenAllKeysPressed(); // Got this far, must all match!
    return true;
}
```

Outside an input field, I don't think ng-keypress works, but the keypress from [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/) might.

I'm sure there should be an array diff kinda function too, but the specific call evades me right now.

Comment: `keypress` will not fire for arrow keys.

Comment: angular gives you access to $document, just inject it....can bind to that

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/t016cWzbH3D37m2bAU4Y?p=preview). I've implemented a simple '2 UP keystrokes in a row' scenario.

You can do it in plain jQuery and communicate the event with a `$rootScope.$broadcast`.

Register the jQuery code in and Angular `run` callback (guarantees that angular has already bootstraped):

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
  var upHitOnce = false;
  $(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 38) {
      if (upHitOnce) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('DoubleUpFired');
        $rootScope.$apply();
        upHitOnce = false;
      } else {
        upHitOnce = true;
      }
    } else {
      upHitOnce = false;
    }
  });
});
```

and then any controller can listen to this event like:

```
$scope.$on('DoubleUpFired', function() {
    $scope.fired = true;
});
```

Binding an `ng-keydown` action callback to `body` is ok, but has a small disadvantage. It fires a `$digest` on every keystroke. What you really want is a `$digest` only when the sequence has been entered when you somehow need to update the UI.

### EDIT

See comments on how to remove actual jQuery dependency.

Comment: I like the fact that it only calls digest when the sequence is entered, but is there any way to do this without explicitly using jQuery?

Comment: jQuery is optional. Angular has a jqLite implementation built-in. Just replace `$(document).keyup(function(event) { ... }`  with  `angular.element(document).bind('keyup', function(event) { ... }`

Comment: To be honest, even `$rootScope.$apply()` is a waste. It initiates a `$digest` for the  whole scope hierarcy. You could fire the event, and every scope that listens to it can explicitly call `$digest()` on itself. That way, only the interested parts of the page will be re-rendered. Check it out [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sw4YnOxCEsLFeVq3khfk?p=preview). Of course, no human being can persive a difference between the two ways and a developer could easily forget it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it:

```
var app = angular.module('contra', []);
app.directive('code', function () {
    function codeState() {
        this.currentState = 0;
        this.keys = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65];
        this.keyPressed = function (key) {
            if (this.keys[this.currentState] == key) {
                this.currentState++;
                if (this.currentState == this.keys.length) {
                    this.currentState = 0;
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                this.currentState = 0;
            }
            return false;
        };
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var cs = new codeState();
            scope.isValid = "NO";
            element.bind("keydown", function (event) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    if (cs.keyPressed(event.which)) {
                        scope.isValid = "YES";
                        console.log("CODE ENTERED");
                    } else {
                        scope.isValid = "NO";
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

What's different about this is it's a directive so if you attach this on the body, it'll apply to the whole page. This also allows for entering the code multiple times.

Plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/tISvsjYKYDrSvA8pu2St

Comment: Does the plnkr work?  I added this to my app directive, it binds to it, but I don't see how to fire it.  When I try the plnkr, it just reports NO to the example. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying 'ctrl+s' or 'commond+s' ( change the commondKey )  to do save, maybe can use like it :

**directive :**

```
(function () {

  'use strict';
  var lastKey = 0;
  //var commondKey = 17;
  var commondKey = 91;
  angular
    .module('xinshu')
    .directive('saveEnter', function () {
      return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown", function (event) {
          if (event.which != commondKey && event.which != 83) {
            lastKey = 0;
          }
          if (lastKey == commondKey && event.which == 83) {
            scope.$apply(function () {
              scope.$eval(attrs.saveEnter);
            });
            event.preventDefault();
          }
          lastKey = event.which;
        });
      };
    });
})();
```

**element :**

```
<input id="title" save-enter="vm.saveTitle()"/>
```

You can rename the saveEnter in directive, with change the save-enter in html.

The 'vm.saveTitle()' is the fuc your want to do.