# AngularJS - Multiple keypress at the same time

Tags: angularjs, keypress

I have the following `$broadcast` to catch keypresses in Angular:

```
$document.bind('keypress', function(event) {
    var key = event.which;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress', event);
    $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress:' + key, event);
});
```

and I listen with `$on`

However, I want to detect when two keys are pressed at the same time, say `enter` and `s` are pressed at the same time (not a combination one one followed by another).

What is the best way of doing this?

EDIT

What I was thinking was to have:

```
var keys = [];
$document.bind('keydown', function(event) {
    keys[event.which] = true;
});
$document.bind('keyup', function(event) {
    delete keys[event.which];
});

$document.bind('keypress', function(event) {
    var key = event.which;
    var keysPressed = [];
    angular.forEach(keys, function(value, key) {
        keysPressed += 'keypress:' + key;
    });
    $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress', event);
    $rootScope.$broadcast(keysPressed, event);
});
```

So if I have multiple keypresses, then I create the correct `$broadcast`. The problem, however, becomes that the order matters now (i.e., if I press `a` then `enter`, then the `$broadcast` is `keypress:58keypress:13` and if I press the other way, I get `keypress:13keypress:58`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Broadcast is used way too much in my opinion.  Instead, maybe use a custom directive?  This is an example of user pressing down <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and it fires an event like so:

```
<input on-shift-tab="prevStep($event,'email')" />
```

```js
app.directive('onShiftTab', function() {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var map = {9: false, 16: false};

    element.on("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.which in map) {
            map[event.which] = true;
            if (map[9] && map[16]) {
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.onShiftTab, {'$event': event});
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
    element.on("keyup", function(event) {
        if (event.which in map) {
            map[event.keyCode] = false;
        }
    });
};
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery answer on this question addresses the problem pretty efficiently, here are some Angular specific approaches:

- [How to watch for a keypress combination in Angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911378/how-to-watch-for-a-keypress-combination-in-angularjs)

A plunker from that discussion that fires an event when up is pressed twice in a row:

- http://plnkr.co/edit/t016cWzbH3D37m2bAU4Y

The example above is able to achieve the same effect as the jQuery answer, but using only one keyup event listener rather than a keyup and keydown. Also has good use of $broadcast to trigger another $on event:

```
var upHitOnce = false;

$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 38) {
      if (upHitOnce) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('DoubleUpFired');
        $rootScope.$apply();
        upHitOnce = false;
      } else {
        upHitOnce = true;
      }
    } else {
      upHitOnce = false;
    }
  });
```

Detecting **simultaneous keypresses** such as `ctrl+r` is a little more involved; Here's a jsfiddle with examples of how to do this in Angular:

- http://jsfiddle.net/firehist/nzUBg/

Comment: I don't want a combination. The link above is if you press `a` followed by `b` for instance. I want to fire up something when `a` and `b` are pressed together at the same time.

Comment: The last example contains a service for managing simultaneous keypresses: http://jsfiddle.net/firehist/nzUBg/

All I've been able to find, will update if I find more. Just trying to help!

Comment: the last jsfiddle was very good, I used that one on my project for key combination handling! thanks!

Comment: when I create a keycombination with the JSFiddle, how to create a combination for numbpad numbers and regular numbers in combination with an alt press? I want that combination to switch accordion tabs on a web page.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for AngularJS that does exactly that kind of capture and is pretty simple to use: [angularHotkeys](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-hotkeys/)

This is an example of the resulting code inside your controller:

```
hotkeys.add({
  combo: 'return+s',
  description: 'Shortcut description...',
  callback: function() {
    // your code here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For modifier keys(Ctrl, Alt, Shift) it's simpler since there are `event.ctrlKey, event.altKey, event.shiftKey`. But for none modifier keys you should use something like this question [Detect multiple keys on single keypress event in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655202/detect-multiple-keys-on-single-keypress-event-on-jquery):

```
var map = {68: false, 69: false, 86: false};

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode in map) {
        map[e.keyCode] = true;
        if (map[68] && map[69] && map[86]) {
            // FIRE EVENT
        }
    }
}).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode in map) {
        map[e.keyCode] = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of that. But I want to make it a service, and make it available where-ever I inject it. I modified my question a bit