# AngularJS execute method on ng-keypress: Ctrl + Enter

Tags: angularjs

I would like to submit text on click on the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but I could not find out how to do that. 
My code 100% works for Enter or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> separate keypress, for example:

```
<div ng-show="hiddenFriendId != null" ng-keydown="$event.which === 13 && sendMessage()">
    <textarea id="messageText" placeholder="Input your message here. Use Ctrl + Enter to send your message" cols="40" rows="3" my-maxlength="3" ng-model="messageText"></textarea>
</div>
```

But while I'm trying something like -

```
<div ng-show="hiddenFriendId != null" ng-keydown="($event.which === 13 && $event.which === 17) && sendMessage()">
```

it is not working (method execution begins on click on the Enter without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).
Can anybody help me with that? I found examples only for a single keypress.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Multiple keypress at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160124/angularjs-multiple-keypress-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Yes, I could implement it as a directive, but, I just want to make sure that there are no simpler ways..

Comment: Directive is the cleanest way imo

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with

```js
// Inside your controller

public keyDownEvent = ($event) => {
  if ($event.ctrlKey && $event.keyCode === 13) {
      this.submit();
  };
}
```

```html
<!-- In your template -->

<input type="text" value="inputValue" ng-keydown="$panelRow.keyDownEvent($event)">
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of writing lines of code just insert code snippet

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Write a comment" ng-model="data" ng-keypress="($event.charCode==10)? myfunc() : return">
```

try using above code for **Ctrl+Enter** press event in the below link

https://jsfiddle.net/smqud8g0/2/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and found a simple solution here https://codepen.io/y__b__y/pen/afFec

All you have to do is create a custom directive on the attribute and use it.
It worked like a boss for me:

**DIRECTIVE**

```
var app = angular.module('yourApp', []);

app.directive('enterSubmit', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {       
        elem.bind('keydown', function(event) {
          var code = event.keyCode || event.which;

          if (event.ctrlKey && code === 13) {
            if (!event.shiftKey) {
              event.preventDefault();
              scope.$apply(attrs.enterSubmit);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea enter-submit="sendMessage()" /></textarea>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> you could use 
`if (($event.code == "Enter" && $event.which === 10))`
If you need <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> you could use 
`if (($event.shiftKey && $event.which === 13))`