# how to trigger function if customer just starts typing

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've been looking around, and I can't find an answer to this.
I would like to have a mat dialog box open when a customer just starts typing. No focus nor input. Just starts typing.
I'm sure the answer is simple, but I just can't find it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19911378/3462319) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24622017/3462319)?

Comment: Not angularjs, angular 7

Comment: I mean similar googling https://stackoverflow.com/q/37362488/3462319, SE isn't really a coding service. At least make an attempt before asking [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple host listener should do the trick:

```
@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
  keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
      this.openDialog();
  }
```

Where `openDialog` is the function that triggers your MatDialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in your input this:

```
<input (change)="doSomething($event.target.value)">
```

Using (change) event you can do something when start typing.

Let me know it worked for you.