# jQuery identify which keys have been pushed

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do a hidden hotkey on my website. i want to make it so that if you type ctrl + dev, and alert will pop up.

here is what i have so far.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey) {
    if (e.which == 4 && e.which == 5 && e.which == 22) {
      alert("it worked");
    }
  }
});
```

it works if i just have one check with out the && but not with all those. I know that might be wrong, but how do i make it work
4 = d, 5 = e, 22 = v in case you didn't know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `||` ([Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR)). `e.which` can't both be 4 `&&` 5 at the same time.

Comment: `&&` means "AND", while `||` means "OR" in javascript.

Comment: you want to use `keydown` not `keypress`, as `keypress` won't return multiple "normal" keys (just a normal key + modifier like shift, ctrl etc).  so it will only return d, e or v not all 3

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954403/can-jquery-keypress-detect-more-than-one-key-at-the-same-time