# Javascript forgets about other keydown when a keyup is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, keypress

I followed [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4954403/938236) to create a multiple key press detector. It works as intended: you press <kbd>D</kbd> and the square moves right, then you press <kbd>S</kbd> while pressing the <kbd>D</kbd> and the square moves in angle. So far so good. However, if you are pressing <kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd> at the same time and you unpress the <kbd>S</kbd>, the square will stop moving. The expected behaviour is that it keeps moving to the right, since you are still pressing <kbd>D</kbd>.

Here's **[a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fX94/1/)** and the **[demo I'm making](http://francisco.io/game/)** (my web).

So, why is `.keyup()` making other `.keydown()` event invalid? This is the offending jQuery code:

```
// Check if it's a function
function isFunction(functionToCheck) {
    var getType = {};
    return functionToCheck && getType.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
}

// Store the keys pressed and callback for each key
var keys = {};
var keycalls = {};

// Loop and call all the needed callbacks
function run_keys() {
    $.each(keys, function (index, value) {
        if (value == true) {
            console.log(keys);
            var fun = keycalls[index];
            if (isFunction(fun))
                fun();
        }
    });
}
// Store a key
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    keys[e.which] = true;
    run_keys();
});
// Delete a key
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    delete keys[e.which];
    run_keys();
});
// Assign a callback to a key
keyboard = function (key, callback) {
    console.log(callback);
    keycalls[key.toUpperCase().charCodeAt()] = callback;
}
// Assign keys
// Assign w to up action
keyboard("w", function () {
    $(".keyboard").animate({
        'top': "-=5px"
    }, 0);
});
keyboard("a", function () {
    $(".keyboard").animate({
        'left': "-=5px"
    }, 0);
});
keyboard("s", function () {
    $(".keyboard").animate({
        'top': "+=5px"
    }, 0);
});
keyboard("d", function () {
    $(".keyboard").animate({
        'left': "+=5px"
    }, 0);
});
```

Disclaimer: this is just for fun and learning, not about having a game engine. I know there are many good ones already available.

UPDATE

One of the solutions I've thought is making an independent loop for calling run_keys(), but I'd like to avoid that if possible. [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/2fX94/2/), however I'm still interested in the problem.

Comment: Umm...instead you need to try with `keypress` event too.

Comment: I tried but [it also doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/2fX94/4/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is coming from the end of *keypress* events after the *keyup*, rather than anything "going wrong", use a *setTimout* loop instead of calling `run_keys` at the end of each handler.

---

Here is an example of a *setTimeout loop*

```
(function looper() {
    run_keys();
    window.setTimeout(looper, 100);
}());
```

It's a bit like *setInterval* but the delay starts *after* the invocation, meaning you won't get (the same kind of) cascading errors as is possible with *setInterval*.

Comment: Yes, [that works](http://jsfiddle.net/2fX94/2/). But why does a keyup on one key stop the keydown on the other? That's what I still don't understand.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia it doesn't, it ends the _keypress_ events and I think _jQuery_ routes _keypress_ through _keydown_ to make life easier

Comment: Okay, sorry, so why does a keyup on `S` stop the keypress event in `D`? Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia It is standard behaviour; in a textbox, hold down a D and you'll see a line of `d`s appear, tap S and then you'll get a single `s` after your line of `d`s, and the `d` will stop even though you're still holding the key down. It must be defined somewhere but I'm not sure where - a quick look on W3 wasn't helpful, may even be OS level as it happens in e.g. Notepad too

Comment: On the other hand with `setInterval()` it can see that it's being pressed. I'll leave it as one of those strange quirks and move on. I can see how the setTimeout solves not only my original problem, but the ones with setInterval, so thanks (: