# Paper.js Event Behavior Differs Between Browsers

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dom-events, keyevent, paperjs

Check out this Paper.js [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/VZDBbsIwDIZfxcoBigQVFy5UfYJdkOhOZIcuuFvUYldJVkCo7z6H0MF8iezvzy//vimqT6i2at9iMN9qqQwfYz/UDgJeApRAeIYdWwqV9Nmi0BRBblheigKtKvRBq4n07G2wTIIGi+fciAydUE3ND5k7YnrD63uf4SBwATdNICWenjvMO/56kCIB26Q+b/EKZQnzYQ6zGaTZiY+2sej8fSfH3Z9frJhEIlQpTFq9Y8Js8o71ELyu/j/K6nmGbLNebtbT7xFA01jI5T4d1m0fFV5tDx/jLw==), where you can attempt to paste the sample item by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. This sketch works in Firefox but not Chrome or Opera (that was the extent of my testing). Why is that and how can this sketch be modified so that I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste the sample text while running the sketch in Chrome?

Note that when you run it, the key event is logged. In Chrome only the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keyup event is logged. In Firefox both the <kbd>V</kbd> keyup and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keyup events are logged.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954403/can-jquery-keypress-detect-more-than-one-key-at-the-same-time

Comment: ^ That looks like it could possibly be relevant.  Possibly you need to also consider keydown to keep track of two keys going on at the same time.
In Chrome, I can get a response from 'V', just not in combination with 'Ctrl'.

Comment: I submitted a bug on github; this commit fixes the issue: https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/commit/a3546e7a79aa3bee66e0f13ef7952c1bc71378c4

Comment: Hi @Scott H if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. There is no obligation to do so but it does help people know there is an answer available.

Comment: @bmacnaughton Could you update your answer with some information about how Paper.js will handle this in the future based on the changes in that commit? Any idea when that will percolate from boolean-fix to develop to master?

Comment: Is there a reason the answer is not accepted? Paper will handle it by detecting that the browser is Chrome and taking the appropriate actions to make sure the keyup event takes place. I don't have any idea when it will make it to master - Jürg is in the middle of chasing down some really hairy bugs on winding and detecting intersections and overlaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that Chrome does not generate a keypress event when the control key is depressed. The logic in paperjs depends on the keypress event to (ultimately) generate the keyup event.

It's a bit confusing but you can take a look at paper's [Key.js](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/develop/src/event/Key.js) starting on the line that begins `DomEvent.add(document, {`. You can see that `handleKey` is only called for a non-special key on the `keypress` event. `handleKey` is the code that inserts the key code into `charCodeMap`. So when the `keyup` event occurs paper doesn't find `code` in `charCodeMap` and doesn't call `handleKey`.

How to get around this?

What you're doing is straightforward, so maybe just using the native DOM event handling will take care of it:

```
document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (code === 'v' && e.ctrlKey) {
        // do your pasting here
    }
}
```

You may need to account for other browser variations, but this should get you started. If you're using jQuery you should consider using jQuery's [keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) function. That handles cross browser issues transparently.

Comment: Apparently Chrome doesn't generate the keypress on Windows and Linux but does on a Mac.