# keydown using Ctrl button

Tags: javascript, keydown

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
switch (event.keyCode){
case 13:
    btnplay();
    $("#short").text("enter");
    break;
case 39:
    btnext();
    $("#short").text("left");
    break;
};
});
```

This works, but instead `case 13` and `case 39`  now I need `case Ctrl+13` and `case Ctrl+39`.

How to do this.

Comment: ctrl is a separate key; you need to detect the ctrl using the same function and set an internal boolean to true, then check for this boolean within your case 13 and case 39

Comment: this question might help with detecting when more than one key is pressed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954403/can-jquery-keypress-detect-more-than-one-key-at-the-same-time

Comment: in `event` is a property called `ctrlKey` which provides a boolean that tells you the Ctrl button was pressed or not.

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331, does it mean `case` inside `case` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.ctrlKey`, example:

```js
$(document).on('keydown', 
 function(event){
  if (event.ctrlKey) { 
 //         ^ here
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 13:
        $("#short").text("CTRL + enter");
        break;
      case 37:
        $("#short").text("CTRL + left");
        break;
     }
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="short">press CTRL + [enter or left]</pre>
```

(For the record: left arrow is keycode 37)

[**See also ...**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/ctrlKey)